# Testing .apk with google play in Amazon AppStore gives no warnings

Tags: android, apk, google-play-services, amazon-appstore

I am working on uploading an existing android application into the Amazon Appstore. My main concern is that I am using google play services for analytics. Amazon provides a [tool](https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/app-testing-service) where you upload an .apk file and they test it on amazon devices and tell you what could go wrong. And, according to [this](https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/support/submitting-your-app/tech-docs/02-submitting-an-android-app), I expected to get an error or warning telling me that I should replace google play services with their equivalent. But, to my surprise, I didn't get anything wrong. Their tests even run my application and took some screenshots, so I don't know what to make of this. Does it mean my application will work? Or should I remove google play services anyways?

Comment: You can also upload the app to run only on non-amazon devices! If you want to support amazon's devices too you have two options. 1: clone the project and for amazon store use their services (library/jar). 2:Keep on going with one project and on the run-time detect the store from which app is downloaded and use the appropriate services.

Comment: You can not rely on devices having Google Play Services, so it would only be advisable to leave it in if your app can function without failure when it is not available. Not 100% sure, but I think they might have grounds for removing your app if it contains any unsupported APIs (such as Google Play Services) - I'd advise reading their Terms & Conditions thoroughly before publishing.

Comment: Does the service you're using require Play Services, or is it just an HTTP REST API. If the latter then you're (probably) okay especially if they can get it to the point where they're getting screenshots. You could check to see if you're running on Fire and use different analytics but if it ain't broken... ;) Did you get any analytics data from their testing? If you share an apk I'm sure folks with Fire's can install and see if you get analytics data returned